# AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-theme, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

I need your help for an issue occured about AppCompat theme. My MainActivity is derived from AppCompatActivity and the theme is declared in the Manifest but when I compile I get this error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

This is the file containing the theme:

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes, text fields and switchcompat button-->
    <item name="colorAccent">#00FFFF</item>
  </style>
```

And this is manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="test_vp.test_vp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/ApplicationName" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do You know how can I solve it?
Thank You in advance

Comment: Did you declare the activity in the Manifest? I don't see it.

Comment: It works also without it because that is the Manifest generated by Xamarin. I only added permission and application tags.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of code you show:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Also, inside this style definition is where you put children definition to only **there** you define characteristics like color etc. It's a case of nested definition. Let me try to clear things:

**First** you define your **main** style which refers to your secondary style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

**Second**, in this same xml you're working, below you define this **child** style, it is inside this where you choose colors etc. Pay attention with the name of this child theme - must be the same you referenced on parent:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
</style>
```

In some cases you will have to go deep inside this nesting, defining things by detailed steps. To resume: you can't change things directly, have to specify every detailed portion where you want to customize.

Comment: It throws Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'

Comment: Have you imported support library? And your **theme.xml** have to be inside **res/values** folder and the code you provided its better to be inside <resources></resources> tag.

Comment: My theme.xml is in the folder values-v21 and yes, I've imported the AppCompat v7 support library version 23.2.1

Comment: I think that was an issue of the environment. I've created the project again, written the same code and there wasn't any error. Also, your ultimate solution doesn't work at all in the old project. Anyway, thank you for the help

Comment: It seems to me the environment didn't load the project correctly so It didn't see the theme section of the appcompat library

Answer (score 0):

try:

`<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>`

It's in support lib, so ommit the "android:" part.